# Android, Opening app only if it is closed through intent action

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am working on a phonegap application, with some native pieces.
So far I have notifications running natively, to make sure javascript and phonegap is not required at all. The problem I am having however, is when the notification is clicked I'd like to open the app, or otherwise just bring the app to the front.

How do I do this?  I tried setting the main activity in the intent, but it restarts my application every time.

```
      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, main.app.class);
      notificationIntent.putExtra(NOTIF_RESPOND, runThis);
      notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      notificationIntent = notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Comment: please add your snippet code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually in Android there is almost no such thing as "restarting application". Basically the Application - is a bundle of all your services/activities/providers etc. It's either running or not.

If user starts a new Activity - system will check, if application is running - it will create this activity inside the application. If no - will create new Application instance.

So I think you mean that if you set intent for your Main activity - another instance of Activity is launching, am I right?

If so - take a look at the following flag for activity, you should try to set in in the Manifest(or whatever in PhoneGap, sorry). http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" 
    ...
```

This flag will tell the system not to create a new Activity each type it will be needed, but to reuse already-existing one. Be careful, you should properly implement `onNewIntent` method in this case to handle this "relaunches", and I'm not 100% sure that it's implemented in PhoneGap.

Good luck

Comment: Hey AlexN,Thanks 
This solved it.

While I am at it I wanted to ask you another question.  Im adding intent extras to the logic that launches the app. I am using an if statement to see if there are extras. Is this considerable proper? Or should I extend the main activity or something when opening it from the notification.

Comment: Putting Extras to the intent that will launch the Activity is the main and the best way to transfer data to it, so I think your are doing totally right.